# Fractions in annotations

Tags: pgfplots

I want to use the `\frac` command in an annotation to a line

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[dashed]coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)} node[pos=0.5,sloped,yshift=7pt]{$\frac{1}{wuv}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the line of the fraction has the same style as the line. How can I get a fraction with a normal line?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the option `solid` to the `node`. I would also increase a bit the `yshift` dimension.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[dashed]coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)} node[pos=0.5,sloped,yshift=9pt,solid]{$\frac{1}{wuv}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

EDIT. Jake is right in his comment: by specifying any version (tested with 1.3), the error disappears. Hence:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[dashed]coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)} node[pos=0.5,sloped,yshift=9pt]{$\frac{1}{wuv}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will lead to the same result.